# Spark UnionRDD cannot be cast to HadoopRDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I need to combine a few RDDs of type `RDD[(LongWritable, Text)]` within a for loop.  For some reason, I have to convert the final RDDs to `HadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]`, but I got the exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD

The conversion seems fine if union is not involved.

Here is the code:

```
 var allRdd: RDD[(LongWritable, Text)] = null

  for (file <- fileList)
  {
      val rd = sc.hadoopFile(file.toString(), 
                           classOf[TextInputFormat], 
                           classOf[LongWritable], 
                           classOf[Text], 
                           sc.defaultMinPartitions);

      // this is fine
      // val hRdd = rd.asInstanceOf[HadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]] 

      if ( allRdd == null)
      {
         allRdd = rd 
      }
      else 
      {
         allRdd = allRdd.union(rd)
      }
  }

   // this line throws the exception :
   // java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD 
   //    cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD
   val allHadoopRdd = allRdd.asInstanceOf[HadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]]
```

Can someone let me know what might be wrong and are there other ways to combine RDDs ?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why your result needs to be a `HadoopRDD`?

Comment: Yes, I need to use mapPartitionsWithInputSplit() method on HadoopRDD.